# NSString wordwrapping like UILabel NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want a wordwrapping for string to just wanted for the dynamic height calculations purpose, because in UILabel NSLineBreakByWordWrapping, counting string height for dynamic purpose is easy to adjust UILabel height please can any buddy let me know the wordwrapping in string ?

```
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
NSString *carNameString = cars.name;
carNameString = [carNameString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\n\n"];

CGRect f1 = [carNameString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:20] } context:nil];
size = CGSizeMake(f1.size.width, f1.size.height + 1);
```

Note: I am using iOS Version 6.3

Edit:
Here is the UILabel Code:

```
    [carLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [carLabel setText:carNameString];
    [carLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [carLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [carLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [carLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to use the size you calculated from the bounding rectangle.
Also, I'd advise you use the same font for your label than you used to calculate the bounding rectangle instead of:

```
[label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

This code should work:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:20];
label.text = carNameString;
```

However, your code doesn't provide the initialization of your UILabel and you don't let us know how you set the frame of your label.
 
If you wish to use it with auto layout, you would have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` and to use the size calculated from the bounding rect to set the size of your container view.
Here's a sample based on your code describing it:

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];

UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[containerView addSubview:label];

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[label]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:20];
label.text = carNameString;
```

Comment: I have added the UILabel as per your request @performat

Comment: thanks i found the solution... so thanks for your updated answer infect yesterday i found the solution by myself hardwork here it is:     [carLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES]; and remove this:
    //[carLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];